# Como fazer append em lista dentro de um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário, índices

Dentro do meu código em Python tenho o seguinte dicionário

```
itens_dict = {
        "Shopid": [],
        "Itens": [{
            "Produto" : [],
            "Histórico vendas" : [],
            "Likes": [],
            "Views": [],
            "Preço": [],
            "Desconto":[],
            "Preço antes desc": [],
            "Marca": []
        }]
    }
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para acessar as chaves dentro de "Itens" e fazer um append.
Inicialmente tentei utilizar

```
itens_dict['Itens']['Produto'].append(produto)
```

No entanto me aparece o erro 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Comment: `itens_dict['Itens']` retorna uma lista, não um dicionário. Você só consegue acessar o conteúdo de listas por meio de indices inteiros. Como essa lista só tem um item, você só vai conseguir acessar o primeiro item usando o indíce 0, ou seja `itens_dict['Itens'][0]`. Esse item de lista sim é um dicionário que você pode acessar valores por chaves, por exemplo `itens_dict['Itens'][0]["Produto"]`. Finalmente, como o valor retornado nesse dicionário é uma lista, você pode usar `append` para inserir um item: `itens_dict['Itens'][0]['Produto'].append(produto)`.

Comment: Perceba que a mensagem de erro claramente diz o problema (se não entendeu por estar em inglês, use um tradutor).

Answer (score 0):

Note que o erro ocorre pois a propriedade "Itens" é uma lista e não um dicionário, ou seja ela utiliza índices como orientação, e você está passando uma "label" de um dict. Para corrigir você deve espeficiar o índice do elemento da lista "Itens" que você deseja realizar o append do atributo "Produto"

utilizando exatametne esta estrutura deveria ser

```
itens_dict['Itens'][0]['Produto'].append(produto)
```